# How to reformat a table

Tags: php, html

I have an extremely simple question, I have a table

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['partnumber'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['quantity'];
echo "</td><td>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

It displays the data, however I would like to have the part numbers displayed on top of each other with the quantity to the right, how can I accomplish this? I've played around with this for awhile and haven't found the solution or been able to correct it myself. I apologize in advance for asking a question of this caliber.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose your rows within `<tr>`

```
echo '<table>';
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['partnumber'] . "</td><td>" . $row['quantity'] . "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I figured I was glossing over the simple solution, I'll mark answered in 10.

Comment: I took out the first echo"<table> since I already had one above what I provided and it put it all back inside the table